# How to design a cosine filter for bpsk using liquid dsp?

Tags: filter-design, bpsk

I was trying to build a (B)PSK-63 modulator as my hobby project.

Here is my code and the link to specs:
[How to modulate PSK63 with liquiddsp?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70893/how-to-modulate-psk63-with-liquiddsp/70929#70929)

Now it is working, but since I am using a NCO to shift the signal from zero to 500 Hz, i have a lot of harmonics:

[image: waterfall]

I have found a function that designs a kaiser filter:

```
unsigned int h_len=100;  // filter order
float h[h_len];

float fc=0.0525f;             // cutoff frequency
float As=60.0f; 
liquid_firdes_kaiser(h_len, fc, As, 0, h);
```

And it works. But as you can see it is a low-pass filter, where I need a band-pass filter.

The specs on ARRL suggest that I use a cosine filter between the modulator and the output.

So, here is the question: how to set up the cosine filter in liquid dsp or what filter should I use instead?